# Delete/Replace Code from LLVM IR

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am working with LLVM IR code. I want to delete instructions from LLVM  IR representation through programs. [LLVM Official documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#deleting-instructions) describing about how to delete, but it is not that clear. Because of some *forward references*, when I try to delete, it throws exceptions.

Eg:

```
`%add2 = add nsw i32 %4, %5`

`store i32 %add2, i32* %b, align 4 `
```

Here, I want to delete  `%add2 = add nsw i32 %4, %5` instruction, but it throws an exception because `%add2` is referred by the second instruction.
 There are `ReplaceInstWithValue` and `ReplaceInstWithInst` instructions, but the usage is not clear from the official documentation.

How to do this? Can anyone help me with some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ReplaceInstWithInst functions when you have two instructions with the same llvm:Type.

For example if you have your `BinaryOperator*` that results in `%add2 = add nsw i32 %4, %5` you can do the following:

```
auto& ctx = getGlobalContext();
auto newAdd = BinaryOperator::CreateAdd(
     ConstantInt::get(cast<Type>(Type::getInt32Ty(ctx)), APInt(32, 42)),
     ConstantInt::get(cast<Type>(Type::getInt32Ty(ctx)), APInt(32, -42)));
ReplaceInstWithInst(oldAdd, newAdd);
```

If you just want to rip the instruction (and probably everything using it) out of the IR you replace do a RAUW with an `UndefValue` like this:

```
oldAdd->replaceAllUsesWith(UndefValue::get(oldAdd->getType()));
oldAdd->eraseFromParent();
```

This will result in something like: `store i32 undef, i32* %b, align 4` and may be removed by optimization passes.

If you want to remove the store as well you have to do it recursively through all users of the instructions:

```
void replaceAndErase(Instruction& I) {
    for (auto& U : I.users()) {
          replaceAndErase(*UI);
    }
    I.replaceAllUsesWith(UndefValue::get(I.getType()));
    I.eraseFromParent();
}
```

However you can consider this function unsafe. It assumes that all users are Instructions. This can break if you have metadata referencing a instruction but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is first RAUW (replace all uses with) for %add2 and then you can safely delete the add instruction.

For example if you know that the result of the add above is a constant (say you're writing a constant propagation pass), then if you have a Value *CI and your Instruction *I you can:

```
I->replaceAllUsesWith(CI)
I->eraseFromParent()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What if the result is not a constant? Can  I replace `%add2` with any other temporary name, say `tempadd` ? If it is possible, how can I do that?

Comment: Any Value can replace this way, if you look at the code from RAUW and the associated comments:


  /// \brief Change all uses of this to point to a new Value.
  ///
  /// Go through the uses list for this definition and make each use point to
  /// "V" instead of "this".  After this completes, 'this's use list is
  /// guaranteed to be empty.
  void replaceAllUsesWith(Value *V);



you could replace your add with a different add entirely, or the result of a load, or anything else.